# Python -Taking dot product of long list of arrays

Tags: python, numpy

So I'm trying to to take the dot product of two arrays using numpy's dot product function.

```
import numpy as np

MWFrPos_Hydro1 = subPos1[submaskFirst1]
x = MWFrPos_Hydro1
MWFrVel_Hydro1 = subVel1[submaskFirst1]
y = MWFrVel_Hydro1
MWFrPosMag_Hydro1 = [np.linalg.norm(i) for i in MWFrPos_Hydro1]

np.dot(x, y)
```

returns

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-135-9ef41eb4235d> in <module>()
      6 
      7 
----> 8 np.dot(x, y)

ValueError: shapes (1220,3) and (1220,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 1220 (dim 0)
```

And I using this function improperly?

The arrays look like this

```
print x

[[  51.61872482  106.19775391   69.64765167]
 [  33.86419296   11.75729942   11.84990311]
 [  12.75009823   58.95491028   38.06708527]
 ..., 
 [  99.00266266   96.0210495    18.79844856]
 [  27.18083954   74.35041809   78.07577515]
 [  19.29788399   82.16114044    1.20453501]]

print y

[[  40.0402298  -162.62153625 -163.00158691]
 [-359.41983032 -115.39328766   14.8419466 ]
 [  95.92044067 -359.26425171  234.57330322]
 ..., 
 [ 130.17840576   -7.00977898   42.09699249]
 [  37.37852478  -52.66002655 -318.15155029]
 [ 126.1726532   121.3104248  -416.20855713]]
```

Would for looping `np.vdot` be more optimal in this circumstance?

Comment: Can you please avoid major edits that change the premise of your question? Your original was "what does it mean when they are not aligned?" I've answered that. If you're asking something else, ask a new question, don't edit this one.

Comment: Suppose `x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])` and `y = np.array([[5, 4, 3], [-1, 0, 2]])`.  Please show the exact output that you would expect in this case.  Those arrays are small enough that you can do it "by hand" and then say "Here's what I want..."

Answer (score 2):

You can't take the dot product of two `n * m` matrices unless `m == n` -- when multiplying two matrices, A and B, B needs to have as many columns as A has rows. (So you *can* multiply an `n * m` matrix with an `m * n` matrix.)

See [this article on multiplying matrices](http://mathinsight.org/matrix_vector_multiplication).

Comment: So instead of using `np.dot(x,y)`, I should just multiply both arrays and just add them instead?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do. Are you trying to get a matrix `C` where `C[x,y] == A[x,y] * B[x,y]`?

Comment: So since these are both 3d arrays, I'm just trying to multiply each of their indexes and then add them to create a new array of the shape (1220,).

Comment: Unless I just make a for loop with `np.vdot`

Comment: They aren't 3d.  They have 3 columns, which may represent 3d coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Some possible products for `(n,3)` arrays (here I'll just one)

```
In [434]: x=np.arange(12.).reshape(4,3)
In [435]: x
Out[435]: 
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.],
       [  3.,   4.,   5.],
       [  6.,   7.,   8.],
       [  9.,  10.,  11.]])
```

element by element product, summed across the columns; `n` values.  This is a magnitude like number.

```
In [436]: (x*x).sum(axis=1)
Out[436]: array([   5.,   50.,  149.,  302.])
```

Same thing with `einsum`, which gives more control over which axes are multiplied, and which are summed.

```
In [437]: np.einsum('ij,ij->i',x,x)
Out[437]: array([   5.,   50.,  149.,  302.])
```

`dot` requires last of the 1st and 2nd last of 2nd to have the same size, so I have to use `x.T` (transpose).  The diagonal matches the above.

In [438]: np.dot(x,x.T)
    Out[438]: 
    array([[   5.,   14.,   23.,   32.],
           [  14.,   50.,   86.,  122.],
           [  23.,   86.,  149.,  212.],
           [  32.,  122.,  212.,  302.]])

`np.einsum('ij,kj',x,x)` does the same thing.

There is a new `matmul` product, but with 2d arrays like this it is just `dot`.  I have to turn them into 3d arrays to get the 4 values; and even with that I have to squeeze out excess dimensions:

```
In [450]: x[:,None,:]@x[:,:,None]
Out[450]: 
array([[[   5.]],

       [[  50.]],

       [[ 149.]],

       [[ 302.]]])
In [451]: np.squeeze(_)
Out[451]: array([   5.,   50.,  149.,  302.])
```